# Button Set-timeout(delay of one second)

Tags: android, image, button, delay

I need help with a very simple program I am creating in Android Studio. There are two different background images. All I want is to press a button, have my background image change to the next image, have a 1-second delay, and then change back to the original image.

I am able to have the background image change on a press, but I can't figure out how to add a delay and change back the background image.

Edit: Thank you guys for helping me out. I am very new to this stuff and I spent a lot of time trying to figure stuff out on my own. Finally got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need `Handler`..

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Change the image back here
  }
}, 1000); // 1 sec delay
```

Comment: Yes i tried that before but, when I put the code to change image back, I get an error saying that my variable needs to be declared final.

Comment: @Justin If you hold on the line which gives you the error, it will suggest that make that variable final because you are using it inside run method. So, whatever you are trying to use inside `run()` method, make it final(add final before declaring it) and then it will work.

Comment: @Justin Declare your variable as class level... or just make it final.. it will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
// set the background here
compositeDisposable.add(
            Completable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(() -> {
                       //update the background
                    }, Throwable::printStackTrace));
```